# Trying to create a function that would retry an input 3 times if the user doesnt answer correctly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, game-development, retry-logic

I want the user to have 3 retries if they guessed wrong, and if they still don't get it they fail the game. I tried a while loop but didn't know how to limit the number of tries.

```
import random

#select range
def getInputS():
    global ranges
    ranges = input('Select range: ')
    while not ranges.isnumeric():
        print("enter a number")
        ranges = input("enter again: ")
    return int(ranges)
getInputS()

#guessing function
r =int(ranges)
item= random.randint(0,r) 

#guess item

answer = int(input("Guess the number: "))
while answer > r:
    print("too high")
    answer =int(input("try again: "))
if item == answer:
    print("Got it")
if item != answer:
    answer =int(input("one more try: "))
else:
    print(item, "is the answer")
```

Comment: There are answers in the duplicate link which limit the number of tries the user gets.

Comment: @quamrana There appears to be only one answer with a positive vote count that does and it uses `chain()`. If a user can't do this without `itertools` then that answer is black magic.

Comment: @quamrana I found something more specific.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Thanks. I'll make a note of that one.